# A way to test Facebook Insights without a Facebook page over 30 likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API to grab values from Facebook Insights, but I don't have a Facebook page to test it on. The one I created has only one like, and when I went to check the page likes the values remain 0.

```
array (size=2)
  'value' => int 0
  'end_time' => string '2015-09-01T07:00:00+0000' (length=24)
```

I was reading through the documentation and says,

> "Page Insights are available after at least 30 people like your Page.
>   Please keep in mind that it can sometimes take several hours for
>   insights to become available after 30 people have liked your Page."

I can't really get down into testing my code (and graphs created from these values) properly without any real numbers... is there a way to test this?

Comment: No, there are no "test pages" or similar. You could ask some friend that manages a page with more likes to give you/your app manage_pages permissions to test it.